Why is there an erroneus Hebrew text, about the completed works on the seventh day?
I quote the Masoretic text chap. 2, 2
וַיְכַ֤ל אֱלֹהִים֙ בַּיּ֣וֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ אֲשֶׁ֣ר עָשָׂ֑ה

Word Analysis-Gramatics
וַיְכַ֤ל (conj. +  verb Piel, imperfect tense, means: he completed)
אֱלֹהִים֙ (God)
בַּיּ֣וֹם (prep.: in + noun: day)
הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י (art. + seventh)
מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ (noun: work + suffix: 3 masc. sing.: of him)
אֲשֶׁ֣ר (reference pronoun: which)
עָשָׂ֑ה (verb Qal, perfect tense, 3 masc. sing.: he made)

Translation
And God completed on the seventh day his works which he made.

I quote the Septuagint text chap. 2, 2
καὶ συνετέλεσεν ὁ θεὸς ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῇ ἕκτῃ τὰ ἔργα αὐτοῦ, ἃ ἐποίησεν.

Word Analysis-Gramatics
καί (conj.: and)
συνετέλεσεν (verb. aorist. tense [as we say: he completed] 3 masc. sing. active voice, indicative inclination)
ὁ θεός (art. + God)
ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ (prep.: in + art. + day, dative case)
τῇ ἕκτῃ (art. + sixth, dative case)
τὰ ἔργα αὐτοῦ (art. + noun: works + possessive pronoun in genitive case: of him)
ἃ ἐποίησεν (reference pronoun accusative case: which + verb aorist tense, 3 masc. sing., indicative inclination: he made)

Translation
And God completed on the sixth day his works which he made.

Note: Also in the Samaritan Pentateuch it is written: sixth. In the Syriac Peshitta Version it is written: sixth. In the Latin Vulgate Version it is written: seventh. In the Aramaic Targums of Onkelos/PseudoJonathan/Neofiti/Neofiti-Marginalia/Fragments-TP-Gen. It is written: seventh.
Αs one can easily understand, for a copyist to change the Hebrew text and copy by changing the day from the sixth to the seventh, requires an extreme motive and beyond all rational conscience. For we know that for the Jews it was from very to fully reverent to observe the Sabbath rest. For I cannot imagine Moses writing that God completed his works on the seventh day.
So, I have two questions:

what made this or these copyist(s) change the text?

What information is there, beyond the "common" information we have from the obscure 1st century AD onwards, about the tradition of the Hebrew text, up to the time of the Masoretes?



According to the information I have (from the book: Εισαγωγή στην Παλαιά Διαθήκη, από το συγγραφέα Αθανάσιο Χαστούπη [translated into the new Greek] = Introduction to the Old Testament, by the editor Athanásios Chastúpis), the Greek translations of the Hebrew Bible of Aquila, Theodotion and Symmachus, which are included in fragments in Origenes Hexaplorum by Fridericus Field, were made between 130 AD and the beginning of the 3rd century, and which are written "seventh".

So there was already "seventh" in the text at that time. It specifically says, in brackets: "Οἱ λοιποί: τῇ ἑβδόμῃ" (= the rest of them: "on the seventh"), referring to these three.

https://archive.org/details/origenhexapla01unknuoft/page/12/mode/2up?view=theater

Here is your answer from an expert in the Torah.


On the seventh day This phrase caused embarrassment to ancient translators and commentators, for it seems to be out of harmony with the context, implying some divine activity also on this day. However, the preposition can easily mean “by,” and the verb can be taken as a pluperfect, “had finished,” or as a declarative, “pronounced finished,” just as “he declared it holy” in verse 3.
--
Sarna, N. M. (1989). Genesis (p. 15). Jewish Publication Society.


Figure 1. Sarna's footnote 3 after "commentators,"

That is the Samaritan Pentateuch, the Septuagint, the Peshitta, and Book of Jubilees 2:1, 16 [2, 27 instead of 1, 16] read "On the sixth day."

Καὶ συνετελέσθησαν ὁ οὐρανὸς καὶ ἡ γῆ καὶ πᾶς ὁ κόσμος αὐτῶν.  2 καὶ συνετέλεσεν ὁ θεὸς ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῇ ἕκτῃ τὰ ἔργα αὐτοῦ, ἃ ἐποίησεν, καὶ κατέπαυσεν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῇ ἑβδόμῃ ἀπὸ πάντων τῶν ἔργων αὐτοῦ, ὧν ἐποίησεν.
(Gen. 2:1–2, LXX)

As far as textual evidence, the Biblia Sacra Vulgata has:

conplevitque Deus die septimo opus suum quod fecerat et requievit die septimo ab universo opere quod patrarat†
(Gen. 2:2)

The way a textual critic would look at the variation between the Masoretic Text and the Samaritan Pentateuch is a copyist would have reason to change seventh day (ביום השביעי) to sixth day (ביום השישי) but no reason to change sixth day to seventh day.  The Targums are also strong evidence for seventh day.
P.S. It isn't difficult to see that we struggle with the Hebrew here look at
אֲשֶׁר־בָּרָ֥א אֱלֹהִ֖ים לַעֲשֹֽׂות
in Genesis 2:3. Even the Jewish Hebrew experts struggle with it.  Because the root of the infinitive לַעֲשֹֽׂות is somewhat of a synonym of the root of בָּרָ֥א, I was tempted to think the infinitive was for emphasis, but apparently that only happens with the same root.  The Hebrew scholars below make me feel like a preschooler at Hebrew, and they didn't suggest this.  Relying on context is probably the best we can do

all the work of creation that He had done This smooth English conceals a difficulty in the Hebrew, which literally translates “all His work that God created to do.” Ibn Ezra and Radak understood the final verb as connoting “[for man] to [continue to] do [thenceforth].” Ibn Janaḥ and Ramban connected the final verb with the preceding “ceased,” thereby taking it to mean: “He ceased to perform all His creative work.”  --
Sarna, N. M. (1989). Genesis (p. 15). Jewish Publication Society.


Ancient translators were embarrassed by activity on the seventh day. How does the source of this statement know this? Is there documentation somewhere to indicate the embarrassment of the ancient translators?

Also: perhaps rest was one of the things that he did

@DavidD your comment asks why an ancient document wrote what it wrote. That is a question to itself, albeit many scholars may debate that and are unable to answer, and such a question may be off-topic for this specific site all depending.

@Jesse I agree completely. The answer to which I asked the question posits the embarrassment of the ancient translators. To your point - we can't know that, therefore the answer assumes something we can't know. To your point, the answer might be off topic.

@ David D added more information on "Is there documentation somewhere to indicate the embarrassment of the ancient translators?"

@PerryWebb Do you know of any books that are like this: “A Textual Guide to the Hebrew Old Testament” ?? — I have one for the “Greek New Testament” but not for the Old.  Might you know?  I already googled a bunch.  Nothing.

Although, there are 24 copies of Genesis among the Dead Sea Scrolls, the manuscripts are heavily damaged and most of what's left are in tiny fragments. None of the fragments identified as from the second chapter provide clues regarding the seventh day. Neither the words "sixth" nor "seventh" day have been identified. However, the fragments that have been identified align closely to the Masoretic text according to The Dead Sea Scrolls Bible by Abegg, Flint, and Ulrich in their introduction to Genesis.
The redundancy in the Septuagint for Genesis 2:3 makes it clear that God did no works on the seventh day. Thus, one can easily conclude that God worked on the sixth day and also completed his works that day.
Two translation possibilities exist, which are equivalent in concept.

God completed his works IN the sixth day. (ἐν, SG 1722)
God completed his works BY the seventh day. (bay·yō·wm, from SH 3117, yom)

The difference in word choices depend entirely on articulation, not in concept. We also have to note that the English language is far richer in preposition specificity (150+) than most other languages (language post-positions notwithstanding).
Addendum
For those who might be wondering what Genesis 2:1-3 looks like in the Dead Sea Scrolls--here's the actual remaining text:

...the heavens...his...which...Go(d)...bless(ed)...(al)l his work...

Perhaps in the future, computer reassembly of numerous (i.e. ~25,000) tiny fragments can recover more of the text. DNA analysis has been used to associate fragments originating from the same parchment. There's also at least one digital restoration project in operation.
See https://www2.cs.uky.edu/dri/dead-sea-scrolls/

The 4Q10 Genesis(k) Dead Sea manuscript contains 1-3 verses, but as you say it is damaged where it says what day.

As for whether God worked on the seventh day, it is clear from 1 ch. 31 v. that before evening came, God had finished his works. "And there was evening and there was morning, THE sixth day" (and also, the sixth day passed); this is indicated by the same Hebrew as the last word with its article.

Answer
The Hebrew text should not be considered as erroneous as Sabbath is part of the creation. God created the seventh day Sabbath, as part of the original creation.
Explanation
The seventh day is part of the week created by God. The seventh day, that is, the Sabbath is very much a part and parcel of the creation. So the Hebrew text is right:

“And on the seventh day God completed His work which He had made” (Gen
2:2a).

How?

“He rested on the seventh day from all His work which He had made”
(Gen 2:2b).


“And God blessed the seventh day and sanctified it, because He rested
from all His work on it, which God had created to make” (Gen 2:3).

Why did God rest? Was He tired?
Not at all (Isaiah 40:28)!
For God, “resting” was an activity since He cannot be tired. And that activity was part of the creation He made.
Other Scriptures agree with this:

“For in six days Jehovah made the heavens and the earth, the
sea, and all which is in them, and He rested on the seventh day;
on account of this Jehovah blessed the sabbath day and
sanctified it” (Exo 20:11).


“for in six days Jehovah made the heavens and the earth, and on
the seventh day He rested and was refreshed” (Exo 31:17).

“Made” in six days and “rested” on the seventh show the two activities God did in the Creation.
In the creation activities explained in the first two Genesis chapters only 2 things are shown as “blessed”: the first human beings (Gen 1:22, 28) and Sabbath (Gen 2:3).
Both are part of the same creation.
Conclusion
So God indeed completed His creation at the end of the seventh day when He created Sabbath.
A Doubt
I couldn’t find the word “six” in the Septuagint that is with me. The Greek says:

“καὶ συνετέλεσεν ὁ θεὸς ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῇ ἕκτῃ τὰ ἔργα αὐτοῦ, ἃ ἐποίησεν.”

A literal translation goes like this:
“And completed (the) God in the day (the) from the works of him which made”. (My effort; could be wrong).
Where is six, here?
(I am not challenging anyone as my understanding of the Greek could be wrong. So this is a genuine question. I will delete it when I get the answer)

Thanks for your response, and I appreciate your help! However, I would like to point out a literal and a free translation of the LXX. Literal translation of LXX: "And (He) completed the (Nominative case) God on (Dative case) the day the (Dative case) sixth the (Accusative case) works of Him (Genitive case), which (relative pronoun in Accusative case) (He) made". Free translation of LXX: "And God completed on the sixth day His works, which He has made".

@GeorgeF – Since you are from (as I understand from your answers) a Greek background, you should be right. But I am surprised because in Greek “six” has “hex” (G1803) used throughout the NT. The “ektos” (G1622) you have referred as “six” is “From G1537; the exterior; figuratively (as a preposition) aside from, besides: - but, except (-ed), other than, out of, outside, unless, without.” (Strong). (G1537 is “Ek” or “Ex” which means “from”).

In the NT, this particular word is used as “outside” (Mat 23:26), “other things” (Act 26:22), “without” (1 Cor 6:18), “except” (1 Cor 14:5), “unless” (1 Cor 15:2), “excepted” (1 Cor 15:27), “out” (2 Cor 12:2, 3) and “but” (1 Tim 5:19). So, what could be the connection between “six” and “ektos” (since I couldn’t find “ektos” used for six in the NT)?

This serial number is in the feminine gender in the Dative case and its inclination in all cases is this: Nominative › ἕκτη, Genitive › ἕκτης, Dative › ἕκτῃ, Accusative › ἕκτην, Vocative › ἕκτη. Here you can search, but it has not the Dative case › https://biblescan.com/searchgreek.php?q=%E1%BC%95%CE%BA%CF%84%CE%B7

Okay, the difference is between “Ektos” (G1622) and “Hektos” (G1623). But strangely the “Greek Old Testament (Septuagint) with Stong’s Numbers” I have with me does not have G1623! Anyway, thank you for this clarification.

your welcome! If there is any other thing that you need it, tell me.
